# Javascript accessing local variable from other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Okay I have this problem. I am using this variable in one function, but I have to reset it in another, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

My code looks like this:

```
var city_flag = null;
  $(".button").click(function(){
    var city = $(this).attr("id");

    if(city_flag == city){
      city_flag = null;
    } else {
      city_flag = city;
    }
  });
```

And than  I got this: (coffescript)

```
$.fn.extend
  somelistMap: (options) ->
    // some settings here

   // on init addCloseClickListenerToInfoWindow called

  addCloseClickListenerToInfoWindow = (id) =>
      google.maps.event.addListener markers[id]["infoWindow"], 'closeclick', =>
        resetMap()
        $(".city_tab").css("background", "none")
        $(".all_dealers").removeClass("row_hide")
        $(".all_dealers").addClass("row_show")
        city_flag = null //Here i have to reset it
```

How can I get this to work? I tried putting city flag outside of the functions, but its not working!

EDIT: Forgot to mention environment is rails.. if that changes something

Comment: declare that variable as *GLOBAL*

Comment: put var city_flag outside your document.ready

Comment: ok i will try that....sec

Comment: `flag` or `city_flag` you seem to be interchanging them

Comment: sorry my bad, in code this was right ;)

Answer (score 2):

declaring global variables is not a best practice but it will solve this specific problem.

use this whenever you access `city_flag`:  `window.city_flag`.

for example:

```
window.city_flag = null;
```

or

```
window.city_flag = city;
```

Comment: I tried this already too. nothing seems to change! 'city_flag' does not reset!

Answer (score 1):

Make `city_flag` as a `GLOBAL var` like,

```
var flag = null,
    city_flag = null;
// ..... your remaining code
```

Also you can use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")` like,

```
var city = this.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this work do the below changes (I dont know your Full coffeescript structure , this is just a assumption)

```
$.fn.extend
  somelistMap: (options) ->
    // some settings here

   // on init addCloseClickListenerToInfoWindow called
//////////////////
  var that = this;
///////////////
  addCloseClickListenerToInfoWindow = (id) =>
      google.maps.event.addListener markers[id]["infoWindow"], 'closeclick', =>
        resetMap()
        $(".city_tab").css("background", "none")
        $(".all_dealers").removeClass("row_hide")
        $(".all_dealers").addClass("row_show")
        that.city_flag = null //Here i have to reset it
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey...i tried everything mentioned, nothing seemed to work :/

So i came up with this solution, i created hidden element and just took my value with `("#hidden").html()` and to reset it `("#hidden").html("null")`

I know it is not the best solution, but this workaround worked!